# recreate flash layer animation in html5 / CSS

Tags: css, html, flash, animation

I need to recreate a flash animation from an old website. This is the Flash animation:

http://igz-inno-life.de/content/IGZ_Uebersicht.html

In the past I would have used Javascript and transparent PNGs to switch between different layover images but in these times of HTML5 I'm sure there is a better way to to this.

I have already done a similar thing with css layers - but in that example all that was required was differetly sized circles and here the layers are a little bit more complicated.

Is there some new HTML5 method to replicate these layer effects or would CSS layers be the most comfortable way to go?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like it would be very difficult to recreate the Flash file from scratch with only html and css (as long as you have the original assets). But if you want a quick easy way you can try just converting it with Google's Swiffy.. https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/ .. you can upload the .swf file and see that it converts it pretty well.. a head start at least.

If you wanted to recreate it all Flash like you can take a look at Adobe's Edge Animate ( http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/ ) .. you can build it up almost just like Flash.

Brian

Comment: Thanks a lot - i just got a cc subscription but I havent gotten around to checking out Edge but I will do that right away! :)